# java random generator

Tags: java, random

I want to generate some random doubles and add them into an ArrayList, but it seems that the nextDouble() function returns a unique double every time, not a new one

```
Random r = new Random();
ArrayList<Pair> centers = new ArrayList<Pair>();  
ArrayList<ArrayList<Pair>> classes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Pair>>();  
for (int i=0 ; i < 100; i++) {
    // Random r = new Random ();
    // System.out.println (r.nextDouble ()) ;
    double a = r.nextDouble () * 10;
    double b = r.nextDouble () * 10;
    centers.add (new Pair (a, b ));
    System.out.println (centers);
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? Is this a mistake of optimization?

Comment: What if you rewrite `r = new Random();` after having calling it? `Random r = new Random(); double a = r.nextDouble() * 10; r = new Random(); double b = r.nextDouble() * 10;`

Comment: What do you mean with "not a new one"? `nextDouble` returns a unique `double`, just as it should..

Comment: What do you mean when you say that nextDouble() returns a unique double and not a new one. Isn't that the same thing? (and the excpected behaviour)

Comment: If you want to reset the seed, you can do as sp00m wrote: `double a = new Random().nextDouble * 10;` etc. If you want to use `a` more than once, do `double b = a;`.

Comment: @Marcus: I want to have 100 different random generated numbers, but in this way, I get 100 numbers that all are equal

Comment: No, the result of `new Random().nextDouble()` is, and should be, a new, unique double generated from the seed used when you instantiated a new `Random` (that is, the current timestamp w/o arguments).

Comment: @MasoodDelfarah: Could you please add an example of the problem you face?

Comment: @MarcusHansson: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org). Something, you can compile, which shows the problem in 20 lines of code should do, for this problem.

Comment: You have it above, and below.

Comment: @MarcusHansson: Your code doesn't show the problem of the TO, does it?

Answer (score 4):

I ran this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Random r = new Random();
  ArrayList<Pair> centers = new ArrayList<Pair>();
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
    double a = r.nextDouble() * 10;
    double b = r.nextDouble() * 10;
    centers.add( new Pair(a, b) );
  }
  System.out.println(centers);
}
```

This was the output:

```
[(8.08, 8.06), (9.97, 1.83), (3.83, 3.19), (2.97, 2.51), (9.40, 2.88), (7.78, 2.59), (1.67, 9.07) ...
```

Isn't that what you want? FYI, this is the `Pair` class I used:

```
class Pair {
  private final double a, b;
  Pair(double a, double b) { this.a = a; this.b = b; }
  @Override public String toString() { return String.format("(%.2f, %.2f)", a, b); }
}
```